# Django: Ajax not receiving data from server response

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

I am pretty new to Django and I am trying to figure out how to add content dynamically coming from a python script without reloading a page.

Currently, I have two functions in my views.py file. One handles uploading a file (home), and the other handles calling a python script and handling the file (handle). The reason I separated it like this is because I want to sequentially populate a HTML table as the python script works with the uploaded file.

However, my ajax function is not receiving any data from the handle function's http response and I am not sure why. **Neither the success nor the error functions are being called**. This is really strange because the print statement in the handle function in views.py prints successfully with data.

**Views.py**

```
i=0
uploaded_file = None


def home(request):

    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        file_form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if file_form.is_valid():
            global uploaded_file
            uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
            print(uploaded_file)
    else:
        file_form = UploadFileForm()

    return render(request, 'personal/home.html', {'form': file_form})



def handle(request):

    # TODO make ajax wait for a response from 'home'
    # so I don't have to wait for 1 second  
    time.sleep(1)
    data = {}
    data['Name'] = fileName(uploaded_file)
    if(request.is_ajax()):
        print(data)        # prints succesfully
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), 
content_type="application/json")
```

**home.html**

```
        <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">

        function post_tables(data) {
            alert(data)
        }


         $(document).ready(function(post_tables) {
            $("#upload").click(function(event){
               $.ajax( {
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  type: "get",
                  url:'/handler',
                  success: function(data) {
                     console.log("over here")
                     post_tables(data)
                  },
                  error: function(data) {
                      console.log("down here")
                      post_tables("error being thrown")
                  }
               });
            });
         });
        </script>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', views.home, name='home'),
    path(r'handler', views.handle, name='handle'),
]
```

Comment: You haven't shown enough of the template to see what's going wrong with the Ajax, but you *absolutely must not* use a global variable like that to keep state between requests.

Answer (score 1):

I explained the whole process ajax django to you. Perhaps your problem will be solved. good luck.

**views.py**

```
def handle(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
        field_example = data.get('field_example')

        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        data = request.GET
        field_example = data.get('field_example')
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

**home.html**

```
<form id="upload">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="text" name=field_example>
   .
   .
   .
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', views.home, name='home'),
    path(r'handler/', views.handle, name='handle'),
]
```

js code in home.html:

```
$("#upload").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'handle' %}",

        type: 'GET',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("over here")
            post_tables(data)
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("down here")
            post_tables("error being thrown")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: First, thank you for answering so quickly. Secondly, I am not sure why the field_example variable is not being used anywhere. Also how would I send data back to the ajax function via the Json response? With this example nothing is being sent back. For testing purposes I am trying to send the file name back by doing something like: 

    data = {}
    data['Name'] = fileName(uploaded_file)   #function I defined
    return JsonResponse(data)

Comment: I send field_example fields in formData variable js code . If you need send coustom field by value do it like this:
$.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'handle' %}",

        type: 'GET',
        data: {
              "example_field": "value_example",
               "example_field2": "value_example2",
        },
       .
       .
       .